# In python how to find out the element

Tags: python, selenium

unable to find the element by id ...

1. login page wroking normally
2. 2nd page also working normally##  driver1.find_element_by_id("submitButton").click()
3. after clicking the submit button it will go to next popupwindow
4. at this window i have error like unable to locate the element by id ## river1.find_element_by_id("ContentPlaceHolder1_txtAdviserCode").send_keys("535343") ##

Comment: and also how to use the python on popup window and get the values from that

Comment: It is not a proper practice just to ask question without showing out the code part and what error you got

Comment: Please include [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    driver.get(self.base url + "url")
    driver.find_element_by_id("username").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys("")
    driver.find_element_by_id("").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_id("").send_keys("") ## here popup window opened after the open the values are not taken by id 
    driver.find_element_by_id("").click()
    driver.find_element_by_id("").click()
```

## here opening a new window and the send keys values are not taken ##
        driver.find_element_by_id("").send_keys("")
        driver.find_element_by_id("").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("").send_keys("")